# SharePoint 2010 - Calculated Columns

Tags: 2010, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I am hoping to get some help with this scenario:

```
IF Date Intake Decision Documented exists THEN (Date Intake Decision Documented – Date Opened)
                IF ≤ 21 days THEN Yes
                IF > 21 days THEN No

IF Date Intake Decision Documented does not exist THEN (End of Quarter Date – Date Opened)
                IF ≤ 21 days THEN In Progress
                IF > 21 days THEN No
```

I tried using ISBLANK scenarios but I could not get it to work.

I tried this:

```
=IF(YEAR([Empty_date])=1899;IF(([Date Intake Decisions Documented]-[Date Opened])<=21;"YES";"NO");IF(([End of Quarter Date]-[Date Opened])<=21;"In Progress";"NO"))
```

but I am getting syntax errors.

I am hoping someone can help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Below Formula

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Date Intake Decisions Documented]),IF([End of Quarter Date]-[Date Opened]<=21,"In Progress","No"),IF([Date Intake Decisions Documented]-[Date Opened]<=21,"Yes","No"))
```

Comment: You saved me - thank you so much! This worked perfectly.